# How to label maximum and minimum points on a DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, date-and-time

I have a list of data points acquired once per day. I want to plot this list of points in Mathematica such that the maximum and minimum points are identified by e.g., a `Red` point. How can this be done? Thanks.

---

*Data:*

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
dataMT103891062day = {{{95, 5, 1}, 0.0764}, {{95, 5, 2}, 
0.0774}, {{95, 5, 3}, 0.0824}, {{95, 5, 4}, 0.0795}, {{95, 5, 5}, 
0.0887}, {{95, 5, 6}, 0.0867}, {{95, 5, 7}, 0.0794}, {{95, 5, 8}, 
0.0731}, {{95, 5, 9}, 0.0686}, {{95, 5, 10}, 
0.0797}, {{95, 5, 11}, 0.0792}, {{95, 5, 12}, 
0.0874}, {{95, 5, 13}, 0.0814}, {{95, 5, 14}, 
0.0809}, {{95, 5, 15}, 0.0775}, {{95, 5, 16}, 
0.0757}, {{95, 5, 17}, 0.0717}, {{95, 5, 18}, 
0.0811}, {{95, 5, 19}, 0.0773}, {{95, 5, 20}, 
0.0743}, {{95, 5, 21}, 0.0767}, {{95, 5, 22}, 
0.0744}, {{95, 5, 23}, 0.0787}, {{95, 5, 24}, 
0.0772}, {{95, 5, 25}, 0.0916}, {{95, 5, 26}, 
0.0801}, {{95, 5, 27}, 0.0724}, {{95, 5, 28}, 
0.0636}, {{95, 5, 29}, 0.0699}, {{95, 5, 30}, 
0.0634}, {{95, 5, 31}, 0.0695}};
DateListPlot[dataMT103891062day, PlotLegends -> "Load Coefficient"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`MaximalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html)and [`MinimalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinimalBy.html),

```
{max, min} = {MaximalBy[#, Last], MinimalBy[#, Last]} &@ dataMT103891062day;
```

Plot them using [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)attribute.

```
DateListPlot[dataMT103891062day, PlotLegends -> "Load Coefficient", 
 Epilog -> {PointSize -> Medium, Red, Point@max, Point@min}]
```

[image]

To label the `max` and `min` points [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html)  can be used as follows.

```
DateListPlot[{dataMT103891062day, Labeled[min, min, {Right}], 
  Labeled[max, max, {Right}]}, PlotLabel -> "Load Coefficient", 
 Epilog -> {PointSize -> Medium, Red, Point@max, Point@min}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Comment: Thanks dear Anjan Kumar. What shall I do if I want to show coordinates of the maximum and minimum points?

Comment: @HadiSobhani Check the edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Variation using `TakeLargestBy`, `TakeSmallestBy` and `Callout`:**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
dataMT103891062day = {{{95, 5, 1}, 0.0764}, {{95, 5, 2}, 
    0.0774}, {{95, 5, 3}, 0.0824}, {{95, 5, 4}, 0.0795}, {{95, 5, 5}, 
    0.0887}, {{95, 5, 6}, 0.0867}, {{95, 5, 7}, 0.0794}, {{95, 5, 8}, 
    0.0731}, {{95, 5, 9}, 0.0686}, {{95, 5, 10}, 
    0.0797}, {{95, 5, 11}, 0.0792}, {{95, 5, 12}, 
    0.0874}, {{95, 5, 13}, 0.0814}, {{95, 5, 14}, 
    0.0809}, {{95, 5, 15}, 0.0775}, {{95, 5, 16}, 
    0.0757}, {{95, 5, 17}, 0.0717}, {{95, 5, 18}, 
    0.0811}, {{95, 5, 19}, 0.0773}, {{95, 5, 20}, 
    0.0743}, {{95, 5, 21}, 0.0767}, {{95, 5, 22}, 
    0.0744}, {{95, 5, 23}, 0.0787}, {{95, 5, 24}, 
    0.0772}, {{95, 5, 25}, 0.0916}, {{95, 5, 26}, 
    0.0801}, {{95, 5, 27}, 0.0724}, {{95, 5, 28}, 
    0.0636}, {{95, 5, 29}, 0.0699}, {{95, 5, 30}, 
    0.0634}, {{95, 5, 31}, 0.0695}};

{min, max} = #[dataMT103891062day, Last, 1] & /@ {TakeSmallestBy, 
   TakeLargestBy}

DateListPlot[{dataMT103891062day
  , Callout[min
   , Column[{Framed[Last@First@min]
     , DateObject[First@First@min]}
    , Alignment -> Center]
   , Below
   , CalloutStyle -> Red
   , CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint"
   ]
  , Callout[max
   , Column[{Framed[Last@First@max]
     , DateObject[First@First@max]}
    , Alignment -> Center]
   , Above
   , CalloutStyle -> Red
   , CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint"
   ]
  }
 , PlotLabel -> "Load Coefficient"
 , ImageSize -> 400
 ]
```

---

[image]